# Add To Timeline button not requesting publish_actions permission

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, xfbml, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-timeline

I'm using the xfbml Add To Timeline social plugin (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/add-to-timeline/), but when I click it the permissions dialog I get just says "Access my basic information" and sure enough it isn't actually getting me the publish_actions permission I need to use the timeline.  I tried specifying the perm explicitly on the tag like so:`<fb:add-to-timeline show-face="false" mode="button" perms="publish_actions"></fb:add-to-timeline>`  but no luck.

This was working fine yesterday and suddenly now it isn't.  I'm wondering if this has something to do with my adding and removing my app from my facebook account multiple times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was driving me crazy for a long while.  In my case, I fixed it by enabling 'Enhanced Auth Dialog' under the Advanced tab of my app settings.

Comment: Even after enabling the enhanced auth dialog (I can disable it and verify the JS loads the old one), and even explicitly specifying the perms option (though I don't think that is necessary), I can still get  the error response `(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions` unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

When asking for `publish_actions` Facebook shows a preview screen of what sort of aggregations your app will create on their timeline.

In other words, if the preview isn't working, Facebook won't ask for the permission so you're asking in vain. Facebook doesn't make this clear in the docs, but everything needs to be perfectly setup with your app on Facebook to get this to work right.

1. Enable `Enhanced Auth Dialong` in the `advanced settings of the app`
2. Make sure you have at least one `action` and one `object` set up in the `open graph` section
3. For *each* `action` you **must** have an `aggregation` set up.

If you do not do all of these steps, there can be no preview and so Facebook won't ask for permission no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I fixed it by doing the below mentioned two thiings.

a. Enabled 'Enhanced Auth dialog' from 'advanced' setting of the app.

b. blanked 'user and friend permissions' along with 'extended permissions' tab on 'auth dialog' page.

I am not sure what it did, but it started working.

BUT.. Even though the authentication works and the posts are reflecting on my timeline, the add-to-timeline button still shows, 'Add to Timeline'..

The other trick i used is to keep checking the app permissions under account setting tab of my profile page.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

From *Apps -> Settings -> Auth Dialog*:

> While in Open Graph Beta, the 'publish_actions' permission can only be
>   requested from developers and test users of your app. The
>   'publish_actions' permission will be ignored if requested from any
>   other user.

I had the `Enhanced Auth Dialog` enabled in the Advanced Settings, yet this did not work until I added a `Aggregation Preview` for the activity. Strange, but true.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The publish_actions permission appears only if the user has added timeline OR if your app is a game. I suppose it will also be available for apps when Timeline will be rolled out to all users...

Comment: My app isn't a game, but I do have timeline enabled for my facebook account.  Also this button was working exactly as expected 2 days ago.